# TCPDF SetAutoPageBreak() messes up scaling of my Footer()

Tags: php, html, html-table, tcpdf, image-scaling

I am using a custom Footer and have set its position with  setY();. However, the content goes on behind my Footer, which means I needed to make my pagebreak higher. This resulted in messing up the size of my footer when I have more than one page.

My footer consists of tables with images inside. The thing that goes wrong, is that the images are getting weird sizes by some kind of scaling! The larger I make my setAutoPageBreak(), the more messed up my footer will become.

I've been at it for quite some hours. I hope someone can help me on this one.

My footer:

```
 public function Footer() {
        $footer = '<table>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="30" height="50"></td>
                            <td style="width: 570px; height: 55px;">
                               <img src="some_image" width="30" height="50" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>                           
                   </table>                 
                ';

        $this->SetY(-60);           
        $this->writeHTML($footer, true, true, true, false, '');
    }
```

TCPDF handling:

```
$pdf = new MyPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);    
set margins
$PDF_MARGIN_LEFT = 20;
$PDF_MARGIN_TOP = 40;
$PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT = 20;
$pdf->SetMargins($PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, $PDF_MARGIN_TOP, $PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
//LTRB
$PDF_MARGIN_HEADER = 5;
$PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER = 60;
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin($PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin($PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks, it also specifies margin-bottom. This scales the footer somehow...
$PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM = 20;
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, $PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

$pdf->AddPage();

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($my_printed_html, true, false, true, false, '');

$pdf->Output('Test.pdf', 'I');
```

Editted:

I noticed the problem only occurs if my footer is below the pagebreak margin. If the footer is above it, the images are normal but the content passes the footer from behind. 
Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: Aside from your problem, I'd recommend not to work with `px` as unit in PDF documents. Use, `mm`, `cm` or `pt` (depending on the document type and what's more familiar for you).

Comment: Ah, yes. I forgot all about it. Thank you for mentioning that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved quite easily, with a lot of regret of losing too much valuable time on this.
When you are using images in TCPDF, always match the size of the image with the desired size you want them to be in your pdf. The setImageScale() does not reach every image if it is outside the page range. That includes the footer, if its position is outside of the page margin_bottom.
I hope you guys won't hurt your heads too much about it and that this will save you all.

Comment: Its here since a while. But thanks a lot. This is really a strange bug. When the footer is inside of the content or touching it, the footer images are displayed correctly on each side. I below it is scaled and mirrored in my case.